# Notification service is not working

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating a cab booking app and I am trying to find location of all nearest cab with help of Gcm notification. But some time Gcm was not working properly. Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you provide some code? And you can try the code [here](https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android/gcm-demo).